# Add page item to either Joomla, Drupal or Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, drupal, joomla

I just want to design this very simple website. Basically there are multiple pages A, B, C... and each page has item A1, A2.. or B1, B2... These items follow fixed HTML template (table,image) and only specific content fields (name, body text..) can be change in the back-end. Backend users can add new pages or new items each page.

Does anyone know some plugin for either Joomla, Drupal or Wordpress that can do the simple purpose above? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress you may create your own [page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates), where you define which parts are editable for the backend user and which are frozen. No need for a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal you can create nodes with content type "page" (standard built in) and then use a module like "[Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)" to display the content. If you browse on the [Drupal site](http://drupal.org/project/Modules) you might even find a module that fits excatly your needs.